# Copy cells values in to next empty row to another workbook vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have two separate Excel files. In one of these in Sheet1 is stored infomration about orders and order numbers. Now every time I make a new order I want this information be collected from my order and inserted in to so called "database" workbook. It should identify the last empty row in column A:A in `C:\Users\user\Desktop\Order_number.xlsx` and insert new values from range `("C6,C17,C10,H18,B32,G32,H6,H9")` to the next empty row. Here is the code I came up to but there is some mistake and it is not working. How it can be fixed?

```
    Sub TransferValues465()

Dim wsMain As Worksheet: Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim wsData As Worksheet: Set wsData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Order_number.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim rngToCopy As Range: Set rngToCopy = wsMain.Range("C6,C17,C10,H18,B32,G32,H6,H9")
Dim c As Long
Dim ar As Range
Dim cl As Range

Dim LastRow As Long

Dim rngDestination As Range

With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Get the last row in Database sheet:
LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rngDestination = wsData.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Resize(1, 25).Offset(0, 0)

For Each ar In rngToCopy.Areas
    For Each cl In ar
        c = c + 1
        'I used this next line for testing:
        '  rngDestination.Cells(c).Value = cl.Address
        rngDestination.Cells(c).Value = cl.Value
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You've declared `wsMain` twice but not declared `wsData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few corrections:

1) `Set wsData = Workbooks("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Order_number.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")` will not work. Either use `Set wsData = Workbooks("Order_number.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")` if the workbook is open. Or you **need to open** the workbook first.

2) I am not famliar on using `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsData.Range("A:A"))` to get the last row. To get the last row in Column A (with the possibility of skipping balnk cells in the middle) use `wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`.

3) My preference is to use **Copy >> PasteSpecial xlPasteValues** with   `cl.Copy` and the following line `wsData.Range("A" & C).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TransferValues465()

Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim wbData As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim C As Long
Dim ar As Range
Dim cl As Range

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rngDestination As Range

Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' you need to open the workbook
Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Order_number.xlsx")
Set wsData = wbData.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rngToCopy = wsMain.Range("C6,C17,C10,H18,B32,G32,H6,H9")

'Get the last row in Database sheet:
LastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

C = 1
For Each cl In rngToCopy
    cl.Copy
    wsData.Cells(LastRow + 1, C).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    C = C + 1
Next cl    

wbData.Close True '<-- close and save the changes made
Application.DisplayAlerts = True '<-- restore settings

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please help with OPEN and CLOSE commands for the file. Order_number.xlsx should be opened, values entered, file saved and closed. Thank you!

Comment: @mrwad try the code now, added the OPEN and CLOSE and SAVE parts.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! The only problem now is that your code is inserting values to Order_number.xlsx vertically. I need them to be inserted horizontally. In other words it inserts all the values in column A, I need them to be inserted in next empty row. 
Please see my code. I have updated it. Now it works fine except Save and Close.

Comment: @mrwad you need to be clearer, putting them in the next empty row, means putting them all in Column A. Do you want them all in the same row ? let's sat that row 10 is the first empty row, so you want tp **PASTE** the values to "A10", then "B10" , "C10" and so  on?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry I don't know all the terms that well! I want to PASTE the values to "A10", then "B10" , "C10" and so on?

Comment: @mrwad try now the edited code (copy all of it and test again)